# Delete Cookies From Another Application

Tags: c#, cookies, command-line

I am not familiar with cookies concept but I need to do cleanup for one of applications.  While I know how to delete files and registries, I am unsure how do I delete cookes for that application.
The application is not running and another application (C# console app) should delete the cookies.  They must be stored somwwhere on the system.  How do I find them and delete them from my command line app?

**UPDATE**
I am on Windows 10
Cookies are stored at location

```
C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
```

How to delete them all?

How to delete only cookies relating to my application XYZ.exe?

Comment: How does the program make its requests? At a guess, you'll be sharing the http stack with IE, but without knowing more...

Comment: so, do you want to delete cookies on your pc using a console app? do you want to remove all cookies or a particular website? what are you trying to achieve?  what is your OS?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete cookies on my PC using my console app.  I have updated the question to give more info.  Thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Here is how I did it

```
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("your cookies location");
    if (!dir.Exists) return;

    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. If you escape the `\` then this resolves to the root directory. This would be disastrous.

Comment: updated.  it does not compile why?  you also need to enter location where your cookies are stored.  In my case, it is working just fine

Comment: It didn't compile because `"\."` is not a valid string literal. Like you said, fixed.

Comment: You can use either something like @"C:\your\location" or "C:\\your\\location" to deal with that.  Hope that helps.